# ACF: How to get users with a ACF flexible content subfield with a specific value AND layout?

Tags: custom-field, users, advanced-custom-fields, meta-query, user-meta

I am looking for a way to query users based on a user meta entry for an advanced custom field which has a given value and itself is from a given layout type.

For example, let's say I have the following entries in the usermeta table for a user:

```
a_flexible_content_field_0_status = 'value here'
a_flexible_content_field_1_status = 'some value'
a_flexible_content_field_2_status = 'more value data'
```

Where `a_flexible_content_field` is a flexible content field that has different layouts, these layouts are stored in the `a_flexible_content_field` usermeta row.

```
a_flexible_content_field = [0 => 'layoutTwo', 1 => 'layoutTwo', 2 => 'layoutOne']
```

Note, that the mapping of index and layout differs form user to user.

Now, how can I get users who have an usermeta row of a layout subfield with a given value and the given layout.

For example: Select all users that have an ACF field `flexible_content_field_%_status` of the layout `layoutTwo` and a value of `some value`.

Thanks a lot!

---

**EDIT**: The layout is *not* a possible value of the meta field, it is the `acf_fc_layout` name, that is stored along the field by ACF. It determines which layout ACF uses for that dynamic field. It holds a map of index and layout name pairs, that have to be checked in the query I am trying to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**New answer**

---

I now have a better understanding of the question thanks to OPs comment and have come up with the following. Not tested!

```php
global $wpdb;

/**
 * @var string $field The flexible content field name.
 */
$field = 'a_flexible_content_field';

/**
 * @var string $layout The flexible layout name.
 */
$layout = 'layoutTwo';

/**
 * @var string $subfield The name of the layouts sub field.
 */
$subfield = 'status';

/**
 * @var string $subfield_value The value of the layouts sub field.
 */
$subfield_value = 'some value';

/**
 * @var array|int[] $users The array we will push matching user IDs to.
 */
$users = [];

/**
 * @var string $map_sql Query for finding all users using the `$layout`
 */
$map_sql = <<<MAPQUERY
    SELECT `user_id`, `meta_value` FROM $wpdb->usermeta 
    WHERE `meta_key` = '$field'
    AND `meta_value` LIKE '%$layout%'
    GROUP BY `user_id`
MAPQUERY;

/**
 * @var array|object[] $map_results Returns array of users and their flexible field mappings.
 */
$map_results = $wpdb->get_results( $map_sql );

foreach ( $map_results as $map_result ) {

    $user_id = (int)$map_result->user_id;

    /**
     * @var mixed|string[] $map An array layouts orders.
     */
    $map = maybe_unserialize( $map_result->meta_value );

    if ( is_array( $map ) ) {

        /**
         * @var false|int $layout_index The position/index of the desired layout.
         */
        $layout_index = array_search( $layout, $map );

        if ( $layout_index !== false ) {

            /**
             * @var string $meta_key Build the specific layout meta key e.g. `a_flexible_content_field_1_status`
             */
            $meta_key = $field . '_' . $layout_index . '_' . $subfield;

            /**
             * @var string $user_sql Query if user has any layout subfield matching desired value.
             */
            $user_sql = <<<USERQUERY
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->usermeta 
    WHERE `meta_key` = '$meta_key'
    AND `meta_value` = '$subfield_value'
    AND `user_id` = $user_id
USERQUERY;

            $user_result = $wpdb->get_var( $user_sql );

            // User has matching values, add them to array.
            if ( $user_result > 0 ) {
                $users[] = $user_id;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The result should be an array (`$users`) of user IDs that use the layout `layoutTwo` and has a subfield key of `status` and value `some value`.

---

**Old answer**

---

If I understand correctly, all you need to do is perform a simple query on the `usermeta` table, like so...

```php
global $wpdb;

$sql = <<<USERQUERY
    SELECT `user_id` FROM $wpdb->usermeta 
    WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'a_flexible_content_field_%_status'
    AND `meta_value` IN ( 'layoutTwo', 'some value' )
    GROUP BY `user_id`
USERQUERY;

$user_ids = array_map( function( $row ) {
    return $row->user_id;
}, $wpdb->get_results( $sql ) );
```

The above will return an array of user IDs that have meta fields with a key like `a_flexible_content_field_%_status` and if the values are either `layoutTwo` or `some value`.

**Example output for `$user_ids`**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 9
)
```

---

**Need the meta keys and values?**

This should do the trick...

```php
global $wpdb;

$sql = <<<USERQUERY
    SELECT `user_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value` FROM $wpdb->usermeta 
    WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'a_flexible_content_field_%_status'
    AND `meta_value` IN ( 'layoutTwo', 'some value' )
USERQUERY;

$results = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );
```

**Example output for `$results`**

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_id] => 1
            [meta_key] => a_flexible_content_field_0_status
            [meta_value] => some value
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_id] => 1
            [meta_key] => a_flexible_content_field_1_status
            [meta_value] => layoutTwo
        )
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_id] => 3
            [meta_key] => a_flexible_content_field_0_status
            [meta_value] => layoutTwo
        )
    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_id] => 9
            [meta_key] => a_flexible_content_field_0_status
            [meta_value] => some value
        )
)
```

As you can see, if a user matches the condition more than once they will have multiple results in the returned array. You could combine them with something like:

```php
$combined = [];

foreach ( $results as $result ) {
    $user_id = $result->user_id;
    $meta_key = $result->meta_key;
    $meta_value = $result->meta_value;

    if ( !array_key_exists( $user_id, $combined ) ) {
        $combined[ $user_id ] = [
            'user_id' => $user_id,
            'values' => []
        ];
    }

    $combined[ $user_id ][ 'values' ][] = [
        'key' => $meta_key,
        'value' => $meta_value
    ];
}

$combined = array_values( $combined );
```

**Example output for `$combined`**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 1
            [values] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [key] => a_flexible_content_field_0_status
                            [value] => some value
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [key] => a_flexible_content_field_1_status
                            [value] => layoutTwo
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 3
            [values] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [key] => a_flexible_content_field_0_status
                            [value] => layoutTwo
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 9
            [values] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [key] => a_flexible_content_field_0_status
                            [value] => some value
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and all the details. It's not exactly what I'm looking for. A custom field of the field type `flexible_content` in ACF produces a row for each entry that is created. All entries have a numeric index, and the index is linked to the layout name of the layout used for the individual entry. So, there have to be some sort of selection of the layout based on the entry in  the SQL query. You have an idea if and how something like this could be done in SQL? Some sort of getting the index and comparing it with the index value stored in the layout map is needed I guess.

Comment: @DavidWolf I see! ACF does store a layout map in the database, however, the problem is that the layout map varies per user so a single database query won't be enough. I've updated my answer with a proof of concept that will hopefully steer you in the right direction.

Comment: **WOW!** Your code looks so _wonderful_, and it's working _beautifully_. Thank you so much. You're legendary.